# Call route twice with different parameters in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to accomplish a URL hash contextual search in ember.js. So far I have gotten pretty far reading the docs and watching tutorials but now I'm stuck.

The problem:

When I visit `/#/search/movie/bob` it detects it should be searching for a movie and performs the query on TMDB (The movie database) API and pulls the movie. When I change `bob` to `lord` in the address bar of the browser the route transitions again and it performs the search. The issue happens when I use the HTML search input field to search again while in the `/search/:type/:query` state. The statemanager does not call the route again.

Here is my router:

```
    App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
      enableLogging: true,
      root: Ember.Route.extend({
        showSearchResults: Ember.Route.transitionTo('searchResults'),
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('search');
          }
        }),
        searchResults: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/search/:type/:query',
            serialize: function(router, params) {
              // App.SearchModel gets its values set by
              // the bindAttr helper in the handlebar
              // template
              return {
                type: App.SearchModel.get('type'),
                query: App.SearchModel.get('inputValue')
              }
            },
            connectOutlets: function(router, params) {
              var type = null;
              var query = null;
              var searchController = router.get('searchController');

              if (params && params.type && params.query) {
                type = params.type;
                query = params.query;

                // make sure the SearchModel has its
                // properties set to be able to display them
                // properly in the search fields
                App.SearchModel.set('type', type);
                App.SearchModel.set('inputValue', query)
              } else {
                type = App.SearchModel.get('type');
                query = App.SearchModel.get('inputValue');
              }

              // display the search bar again
              router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('search');

              // perform a search against an API
              searchController.search(type, query, function(data) {
                  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('search_results', 'searchResults', data);
              });
            }
          })
        })
    });
```

Here is the handlebars template:

```
     <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search-view">
        {%  verbatim %}
            <form class="form-inline">
                {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.SearchModel.inputValue" class="span7" placeholder="Search Movies - TV Shows ..." }}
                <input type="hidden" {{bindAttr value="App.SearchModel.type"}} />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" {{action showSearchResults on="click"}}>Search</button>
            </form>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </script>
```

When you click the submit button it calls `showSearchResults` and transitions as long as you havent completed a search before. This happens correctly if I am on the initial `/` state but not if I am on the `/search/:type/:query` state.

Do I need to manipulate the hash location to get this to transition again? or is there a better idiomatic way of telling ember that when I click the search button it should change the `:query` so the state changes?

**Update:**

I got it to work however it feels really hacky .. there must be a better way of doing this? Here is my solution:

```
    showSearchResults: function(router, e, b) {
      // set the hash location so it knows to transition
      // to searchResults correctly .. this feels very
      // hacky ..
      var hashLocation = Ember.HashLocation.create();
      hashLocation.setURL('/search/%@/%@'.fmt(
        App.SearchModel.get('type'),
        App.SearchModel.get('inputValue')
      ));
      router.location = hashLocation;
      router.transitionTo('searchResults');
    }
```